# Can we bundle and reference the Microsoft Access engine as a part of our binaries for deployment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

We are currently developing functionality that makes use of the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver server-side to interface with MS-Excel files.  While I know that the [Microsoft Access Database Engine Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255) is available, I believe that the security managers of the deployment environment will freak out a little bit about running a full setup.exe just for one app (of many) on the shared environment.

So, can we just bundle and reference these DLLs as a part of our build or are we stuck with a full blown deployment using the Microsoft .exe?

Answer (score 3):

Unless stated explicitly anywhere, the DLLs are not redistributable other than via the redistributable package to which you link.

Standard practise from Microsoft is to force you to use the redistributable package, presumably in an effort to avoid lots of bad user experience from botched manual installations. So I think you will just have to accept the deployment of this package.