# Add Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 as reference/include in deployment?

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2017, driver, oledb

I have painstakingly managed to get my project working after installing the  2007/2010 Access database drivers but i want to build my project so that it can be run on a user's machine without them having any drivers installed (nor even have Microsoft Access)

I'm fairly new to visual studio and C# as a junior, but i think the right approach is to add reference to the DLL of these drivers to the project or find some other way to package it within

The difficulty is that i can run the program fine on my machine but i have to accommodate other user's machines / get them to do the testing etc

Any help/advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we add Reference of 'Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0.dll' to project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380388/can-we-add-reference-of-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-dll-to-project) and [Can we bundle and reference the Microsoft Access engine as a part of our binaries for deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8990079/62576)

Comment: Almost all articles I've read just suggest installing the drivers. Including that one. I had read that page before

Comment: You can't just *install the drivers*, as the linked questions clearly explain. You need to include the required redistributable installer with your app, which is provided by MS, which will properly and (legally according to MS's requirements) install them.